# How to Group new orders, old orders of each day in the total month in Sql 2012

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, datetime, group-by

I need report like this.

I have two tables `Orderdetails`,`Customer`, based on `registerdate` assuming new orders, reaming old orders, i want data from 12-01-2015 to 12-31-2015 on each day:

```
OrderDate    New_Orders Old_Orders
12/01/2015      20            30
12/02/2015      30            50
12/03/2015      20            45
```

Comment: What data? whats your expected output? sum of this columns by month?

Comment: I need Total Orders in the Particular Day.. Total orders 70 and new-30,old-40

Comment: you mean 12/01/2015 - new-20 old-30 and total-50 ? give us examples of output

Comment: Don't tag products not involved, especially since MySQL and MS SQL Server have different date/time functionality.

Comment: Out Put:12/01/2015      20            30
12/02/2015      30            50
12/03/2015      20            45

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM Orderdetails O
INNER JOIN Customer c on c.id = o.id
WHERE 
  o.From_date >= '2013-01-03'
  AND 
  o.To_date <= '2013-01-09'
```

Comment: select Count(*) total,datepart(day, od.OrderDate) as day from orderdetails od 
inner join  customer c on od.customerid=c.customerid 
where convert(Varchar(30),od.orderdate,101) = convert(Varchar(50),c.registereddate,101)
and od.orderdate >= '12-01-2015' and od.orderdate <= '12-31-2015' and od.transactionid is not null and 
(datepart(day, od.OrderDate) >=1 and (datepart(day, od.OrderDate) <=31)) group by datepart(day, od.OrderDate)                                           --here 31st day missing